# How to selectively assign from one Partial to another in typescript

Tags: typescript

In the TypeScript code snippet below, I need to assign from one object to another where both of them are `Partial<InjectMap>`. Here, my intuition says that typescript should be able to understand what is going on because at line (B), the type of `key` is `typeof InjectMap`. So, it should be able to assign values from `input` to `output` correctly.

```
export interface InjectMap {
    "A": "B",                          // line (A)
    "C": "D"
}
type InjectKey = keyof InjectMap;

const input: Partial<InjectMap> = {};
const output: Partial<InjectMap> = {};
const keys: InjectKey[] = []

for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    const key = keys[i]                // line (B)
    output[key] = input[key]           // line (C)  - Gives Error
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAgJYDs4hgMwIYGMQICSKAViLnALLYQIDewCTCARAIIsBcrAQiwDSNmLAMJdWAERbAAvsDgBPCAWJkKAaRAKEAXgQBrLVExFS5KjQDcwYLigoAzolQQArnG4AFbPCTYANgA8qubUEAB8uvQy1naOiFDubh4I3r4BwWYUYZF6dDG29k4GWg7cIRpaANoAulG1NsCYsAgAFP4gzlEADJbICIElCg4AdB0oAOZwABZ9SADU8wCU9EJMccWG2npbDlVINWsIiXDJVVt1ei7u51qHckA)

But it gives the following error at line (C):

```
Type '"B" | "D" | undefined' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
  Type '"B"' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
```

Strangely, the error goes away if I comment line (A). Is this a shortcoming in TypeScript or am I missing something?

Comment: `output[key] = "B"` This also produces an error - Type '"B"' is not assignable to type 'undefined'. To me it seems more like a bug

Comment: looks like an issue related to string literals. do you really intend defining `B` and `D` or is it just for the example? if so, replacing them with interfaces will solve the problem

Comment: @AlonYampolski That was a really good observation! That was an example. I believe the question still stands but it does not bock me.

Comment: it's because input[key] is undefined.

Comment: @r3wt if you remove `Partial`, error remains

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is a bug, it is almost always unsafe to mutate the values and TS just tries to make it safe.

Let's start from `InjectMap` interface.

It is clear that you cant have illegal state like:

```js
const illegal: InjectMap = {
    "A": "D", // expected B
    "C": "B" // expected D
}
```

This is important.

Let's proceed with our loop:

```js
interface InjectMap {
    "A": "B",
    "C": "D"
}
type InjectKey = keyof InjectMap;

const input: Partial<InjectMap> = {};
const output: Partial<InjectMap> = {};

const keys: InjectKey[] = []


for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    const key = keys[i];

    const inp = input[key] // "B" | "D" | undefined
    const out = output[key] // "B" | "D" | undefined

    output[key] = input[key]
    
}
```

Because `key` is dynamic, TS is unsure whether it `B`, `D` or `undefined`. I hope that you are agree with me, that in this place correct type of `inp` is `"B" | "D" | undefined`, it is expected behavior, because type system is static.

Since, `input` and `output` are not binded by `key`, TS wants to avoid illegal state. To make it clear, consider next example, which is equal to our

```js
type KeyType_ = "B" | "D" | undefined

let keyB: KeyType_ = 'B';
let keyD: KeyType_ = 'D'

output[keyB] = input[keyD] // Boom, illegal state! Runtime error!
```

As you might have noticed, `keyB` and `keyD` have the same type but different values.

Same situation you have in your example, TS is unable to figure out the value it is able to figure out only type.

If you want to make TS happy, you should add condition statement or typeguard:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    const key = keys[i];

    if (key === 'A') {
        let out = output[key] // "B"
        let inp = input[key] //  "B"

        output[key] = input[key] // ok
    }

    if (key === 'C') {
        let out = output[key] // "D"
        let inp = input[key] //  "D"

        output[key] = input[key] // ok
    }
}
```

Please keep in mind, when you mutate your values, you loose type guaranties.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67834191/why-can-i-index-by-string-to-get-a-property-value-but-not-to-set-it/67836124#67836124) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67660342/why-does-typescript-say-this-variable-is-referenced-directly-or-indirectly-in-i) question about mutations.

Also this [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RH49aarW6sU) of Titian Dragomir Cernicova is pretty good.

Here you have an example of unsafe mutation, taken from @Titian 's talk:

```js
type Type = {
    name: string
}

type SubTypeA = Type & {
    salary: string
}

type SubTypeB = Type & {
    car: boolean
}

type Extends<T, U> =
    T extends U ? true : false


let employee: SubTypeA = {
    name: 'John Doe',
    salary: '1000$'
}

let human: Type = {
    name: 'Morgan Freeman'
}

let director: SubTypeB = {
    name: 'Will',
    car: true
}


// same direction
type Covariance<T> = {
    box: T
}

let employeeInBox: Covariance<SubTypeA> = {
    box: employee
}

let humanInBox: Covariance<Type> = {
    box: human
}

// Mutation ob object property
let test: Covariance<Type> = employeeInBox

test.box = director // mutation of employeeInBox

const result_ = employeeInBox.box.salary // while result_ is undefined, it is infered a a string


// Mutation of Array
let array: Array<Type> = []
let employees = [employee]
array = employees
array.push(director)

const result = employees.map(elem => elem.salary) // while salary is [string, undefined], is is infered as a string[]

console.log({result_,result})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKu0F4oG8BQUNQHYEMC2EAXFAM7ABOAllgOaoC%20qqokUAygK4BGckAglCS9oAMhTpMJHABsc5EMTJVaDJi2ice8AEKDY8KGLSYoAYznEuAeyvSIOLKuYGAogA9gELABMSAHhgAGigAVQA%20QQkMGCgIDy9fUKgAfigKDmhiADMZEggmVDtgWLwwaSsQCCJ2bmEBJGNMXAJiAHIAKSsACywoABErCFbAqNIZOQUoVoBGAAZ5gBJWpyKoLo48B2JhPUaMZurWgFkrchoHKAAxcirNrGXGQohi70ob02BT4k1hXQbRg5tADqlGk0mGo3M5GI6Xyj1QAHoEWMCFBXu9gJQrI51FAAMJWABuckoDlMEACEX%20Jmsbm2K2eJTKFSqAEksNorHT8USSWSKT94HwqeIaVziBBSuVKnCmKt1nd2ZzuQTiVR%20QF4CK9lBacQFQ4nEioEcOMAcJjsVArFxrVwAFYQD5QMDkKyQcigJ7FTxkYiqvlYcmayAiyXMmVKrlqCBkAB0tL06Kdn3IUGNeDNFqxvSsWSZ0rZHOjqFM2LIUBuJA40mAAH09OHCxAo24E1y41JZPJ08iAO5dUHQKs1%20tQSgkKAcHwQLLUCDeYKUYoT8dYLIQG7eKA4HekCjUOhMY2m82W3P5vjkcg4EDenfX2-EK83kAhiAigDaAF1702WbGeifv%20Mq-nIr6NlKAEkKg4G3nGYAcCQXQABTJh8pwAJRMGWWAViOtaQRGVQkHGmxgChEB2HgggRFRkqduM8iYb2UADkOYzdiA46Tp%20SiHsE07eLO87eN%20S6Tqu1AbluO6Tru-G0D%20OHlrYEBxuUNAocgBH1oEun0JhQA)

**How to fix it ?**

Please, let me know if it works for you:

```js
export interface InjectMap {
    "A": "B",
    "C": "D"
}

const assign = <Input extends InjectMap, Output extends InjectMap>(
    input: Partial<Input>,
    output: Partial<Output>,
    keys: Array<keyof InjectMap>
) => keys.reduce((acc, elem) => ({
    ...acc,
    [elem]: input[elem]
}), output)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAgJYDs4hgMwIYGMQICSKAViLnALLYQIDewCTCARAIIsBcrAQiwDSNmLAMJdWAERbAAvsGC4oKAM6Jsy5UgDmKBAF4EAHmIQAronDoUAE2VFS5KjX4IA8ubMWwV2-bIVqCAA%20AAohJlRPbgAFbHgkbAAbYxRPIMFmBCgPcxi4uATk9zg0jOYAaxAAT2VuNhgYbCrDSqqoTD9HQKDgAEp9IIRW5QA6GBBrU3wQkLxcFxBEkABbfr1BkIZMkZ25sqYAbUWVgF1uSPMjpeWT2V6XbJLzXqA)

**UPDATE**

> why does this analysis apply for [elem]: input[elem]? input[elem] can again be "B"|"D"|undefined and thus the compiler should give error again. But, here compiler is intelligent to know that the type of input[elem] applies for [elem]. What is the difference?

That is a very good question.

When you create new object with computed key, TS makes this object `indexed by string`, I mean, you can use any string `prop` you want

```js
const computedProperty = (prop: keyof InjectMap) => {
    const result = {
        [prop]: 'some prop' //  { [x: string]: string; }
    }

    return result
}
```

It gives you more freedom but also provides a bit of unsafety.

> With great power comes great responsibility

Because now, unfortunately, you can do this:

```js
const assign = <Input extends InjectMap, Output extends InjectMap>(
    input: Partial<Input>,
    output: Partial<Output>,
    keys: Array<keyof InjectMap>
) => keys.reduce((acc, elem) => {  

    return {
        ...acc,
        [elem]: 1 // unsafe behavior
    }

}, output)
```

As you might have noticed, return type of `assign` function is `Partial<Output>`, which is not true.

Hence, in order to make it completely type safe you can use with [typeguards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards), but I think it will be overcomplicating

Comment: Thank you so much for spending so much time on this query! Just one last niggle of doubt: why does this analysis apply for `[elem]: input[elem]`? `input[elem]` can again be `"B"|"D"|undefined` and thus the compiler should give error again. But, here compiler is intelligent to know that the type of `input[elem]` applies for `[elem]`. What is the difference?

Comment: I hope this does not come off as ungrateful. I read everything and now I have much better understanding of how TypeScript works under the hood. :)

Comment: Thanks for the update! I understand every bit and corner of the answer now. This was really eye-opening. :D

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful. Btw, you can find more examples in my blog https://catchts.com/

Comment: Will check it gladly!