# Cannot dynamically set interface object's property values

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
interface MyType {
    a: string;
    b: number;
}

class SomeClass {
    // ... more things going on

    beta: MyType = {a: 'Lorem', b: 3};

    myFunction(alpha: MyType) {
        // beta is an object of type MyType
        for (const key in alpha) {
            this.beta[key as keyof typeof this.beta] = alpha[key as keyof typeof alpha] ?? '';
        }
    }
}
```

see identical playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8Aq6AOKDeAUMicnAFzIDOYUoA5gNzGkBGlIArgLavTMBfQoQQAbOFSrIAygHtuEAMLjJyIqWQB6TcgB0+5N1lQUYABYMp9WQ2SyQwjXzAU0WXCgC8a1wHIAMsYQ3L4ANMjsyADMAswsJNzoAGKcIAhgwPYAFHCiOGauGNh4AJRq8RpaOs5wyMBScCB2rABWEOl2MMhgHm7FEBUaMMbIWQj2NMgA1hDodU25+XBl6pVr5vW6NQDaM3MS07OyXT14x90WVFsQLgC6yN6LBbuzZFJ756cQ509w9wD8-2Qvl8zDWJCEGiEAiAA).

However, this produces the error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string | number | symbol' can't be used to index type 'MyType'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'MyType'.
```

I've tried playing around with it for a long time, tweaking it, and it still doesn't work -- I've no idea why. (I'm using `keyof typeof this.beta` for simplicity but `keyof MyType` doesn't work either).

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: In case the error message isn't clear, the compiler is complaining because it sees `key` as a `string` (since the `in` operator is used) and it cannot find a type indexer on `MyType` (e.g. `{ [k: string]: any }`). I don't believe the compiler is smart enough to infer that a string like `'a'` corresponds to the `a` property, which has a `string` value type. Ultimately, I can't see a solution at all with the `in` loop approach here. You could consider `Object.assign` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67857960/how-to-selectively-assign-from-one-partial-to-another-in-typescript/67860407#67860407) question is very similar to yours.

Consider this example:

```js
interface MyType {
    a: string;
    b: number;
}

class SomeClass {
    beta: MyType = { a: 'Lorem', b: 3 };

    myFunction(alpha: MyType) {
        // beta is an object of type MyType
        for (const key in alpha) {
            const x = this.beta[key as keyof MyType]   // string | number
            const y = alpha[key as keyof typeof alpha] // number | number

            this.beta[key as keyof MyType] = alpha[key as keyof typeof alpha] ?? ''; // expected error
        }
    }
}
```

As you see, `x` and `y` can be a `string` or `number`.

```js
declare var x: string | number;
x = 42;
x = 'str'
```

Since TS is about static type checking, it is unable to figure out whether `this.beta[key]` has same type as `alpha[keys]`, they both are `string | number`.

You are getting `Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'`

This is because objects are contravariant in their key types. And candidates for the same type variable in contra-variant positions causes an intersection type to be inferred.  Hence `string & number` gives `never`.

My advise - don't mutate values in typescript.

You can find more explanations and examples in [my blog](https://catchts.com/mutations)

**How to fix it?**

```js
interface MyType {
    a: string;
    b: number;
}

class SomeClass {
    beta: MyType = { a: 'Lorem', b: 3 };

    myFunction(alpha: MyType) {
        const result = (Object.keys(alpha) as Array<keyof MyType>).reduce<MyType>((acc, elem) => ({
            ...acc,
            [elem]: alpha[elem]
        }), this.beta)

        this.beta = result
    }
}
```