# forEach couldn't get correct types

Tags: typescript

```
declare function a(props: number): number;
declare function b(props: string): string;
declare function c(props: boolean): boolean;

type GenHooks<H extends (...args: any[]) => any> = [H, Parameters<H>]

const obj = {
    a: [a, [1]] as GenHooks<typeof a>,
    b: [b, ['2']] as GenHooks<typeof b>,
    c: [c, [false]] as GenHooks<typeof c>,
} as const

type ObjType = typeof obj;
type Names = keyof typeof obj;

const keys = Object.keys(obj) as Names[];

let out: {
    [K in Names]: ReturnType<ObjType[K][0]>
}
```

when i try to use forEach, it will error

```
keys.forEach(name => {
    const [fn, args] = obj[name];
    out[name] = fn(...args) // A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.(2556)
})
```

it's types will get

`const args: [props: number] | [props: string] | [props: boolean]`

and then i get an error message:
`Type 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2322)`

but when don not use forEach, it's ok

```
const [fn, args] = obj.a;
fn(...args)
```

Answer (score 1):

**First issue** is in this line `fn(...args)`.

Here, `fn` is a union of three functions `((props: number) => number) | ((props: string) => string) | ((props: boolean) => boolean)`.

Please read [this section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types):

> Likewise, multiple candidates for the same type variable in contra-variant positions causes an intersection type to be inferred.

It means that when you are trying to call `fn`, all types of arguments are intersected instead of unionizing. Hence `fn` expects `number & string & boolean` instead of `number | string | boolean`. Please keep in mind that `number & string & boolean` is impossible type and it infered as `never`.

You can find more explanation in my [article](https://catchts.com/react-props).

**Second issue** is in this line `out[name]`. It is impossible to assign return type of `fn(...args)` to `out[name]`.

Assume `fn(...args)` compiles and returns `string|number|boolean`. In the same way works `out[name]`. It also expects a union of `stirng|number|boolean`.
Consider this exmaple:

```js
    out[name] = 'str'
    out[name] = 42
    out[name] = true
```

All three expression causes an error, because TS is unsure about exact value of `name` because we are inside a loop.
`name` can be `a|b|c` an all of them expects different types. In order to assign any value to `out[name]`, you should check the type of `name`.

```js
  if (name === 'a') {
        out[name] = 42 // ok
    }
```

Please see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67857960/how-to-selectively-assign-from-one-partial-to-another-in-typescript/67860407#67860407) with similar issue and my [article](https://catchts.com/mutations) about mutations in typescript.

However, there several workarounds.