# Type 'string | boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: typescript

```
interface modal {
    name: string;
    check: boolean;
}

type Key = "name" | "check";

const obj: modal = fn();

function fn():any {
    return {
        name: "hello"
    }
}

class Modal {
    name: string;
    check: boolean;
    constructor() {
        this.name = "";
        this.check = false;
        Object.keys(obj).forEach((key: string) => {
            this[key as keyof modal] = obj[key as keyof modal];
        })
    }
}
```

I get an error at this[key as keyof modal]

Error message: Type 'string | boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
[image]

Comment: Inside the `Modal` class, `keyof modal` won't allow you to index into a `Modal` object even though it happens to have the same keys as `modal`, an unrelated interface. You need `keyof Modal`.

Comment: You mean change to this[key as keyof Modal] instead of this[key as keyof modal]? Unfortunately, it does not work neither

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Object.keys` always return `string[]`, no matter what. Of course, it is expected that it returns `Array<keyof typeof obj>` in this case, but it is not true.
Please see [this list of issues](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20503#issuecomment-349746286) on github.

First thing that should be done in this case is `type assertion`.

```js
(Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof typeof obj>)
```

However, this is not the end.
There is still an error here:

```js
this[key] = obj[key]; // error
```

In general, TS does not like mutations. Please see [my article](https://catchts.com/mutations) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67857960/how-to-selectively-assign-from-one-partial-to-another-in-typescript/67860407#67860407) answer.

Type of `this[key]` and `obj[key]` is `string | boolean`.

Please see this code:

```
type Key = "name" | "check";

let _name: Key = 'name'
let _check: Key = 'check'
obj[_name] = obj[_check] // error
```

Above code is almost equal to yours, except, your mutation is inside of iterator and mine is not. There is no binding between iteration index and type of `key`.

See example:

```js
(Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof typeof obj>)
  .forEach((key, index) => {
    if (index === 0) {
      const test = key // keyof modal and not "name"
    }
  })
```

It is correct behavior, because even JS specification does not give you a guarantee that first `key` is `name`. JS engine reserves the right to return you keys in any order. Sure, in 99.99% cases you will get the expected order, but it does not mean that you have a guarantee.

So, why do we have `never` in the error message ? TypeScript makes an intersection of expected keys (of union) because it is safer to get common type. Intersection of `string & boolean` - gives you `never`, this is why you have this error message.

---

I believe the best you can do without using `type assertions` is to call `reduce`:

```js
interface modal {
  name: string;
  check: boolean;
}

type Key = "name" | "check";

const obj: modal = fn();

function fn(): any {
  return {
    name: "hello"
  }
}

class Modal implements modal {
  name: string;
  check: boolean;
  constructor() {
    this.name = "";
    this.check = false;
    const result = (Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof typeof obj>)
      .reduce((acc, key) => ({
        ...acc,
        [key]: obj[key]
      }), this)
    Object.assign(this, result)
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NnXOaW)
It worth using `implements modal` or capitalize `modal` interface.