# Indexing with keys of optional parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-types

```
export interface IHtmlProperties {
    website?: string
    favIcon?: string;
}


function getHtml(htmlTemplate: string, properties: IHtmlProperties) {
        const options : IHtmlProperties = {
                    website: properties.website,
                    favIcon: properties.favIcon
                };

        let html = htmlTemplate;

        Object.keys(options).forEach(function(key) {
            html = html.replace('{{' + key + '}}', options[key]);//<==== Error
        });
        return html;
}
```

Accessing options[key] throwing error as below

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'IHtmlProperties'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'IHtmlProperties'.
```

If IHtmlProperties doesn't have optional params, I can easily write options[key as keyof IHtmlProperties].

But here IHtmlProperties has some optional parameters. Any idea how to solve this?

**Update with fix**
The earlier problem is because of replace having the value of undefined. So checking for value validity fixed the error

```
        let html = htmlTemplate;

        (Object.keys(options)).forEach(function(key) {
            const value = options[key as keyof IHtmlProperties];
            if(value) {
                html = html.replace('{{' + key + '}}', value);
            }
        });
        return html;
```

The accepted answer helped me in figuring it out! Thanks for that!

Comment: I hope [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70753101/type-string-boolean-is-not-assignable-to-type-never-type-string-is-not/70753520#70753520) helps

Comment: Please let me know if [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wk5p0N) helps

Comment: Looks so. can you please explain it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70753101/type-string-boolean-is-not-assignable-to-type-never-type-string-is-not/70753520#70753520) answer, it is related in terms of using `Object.keys`.
So, you already know that `Object.keys` returns array of strings. It means that `key` in `forEach(function(key)` is not related to type of `options`. In other words, you can use only `website` and `favIcon` as an index for `options` whereas type of `key` is much wider, it is a `string`.

Type `string` is a super type of `"website" | "favIcon"` (`keyof IHtmlProperties`), hence it is not allowed to use. Imagine you can use any string as a `key`: `options["any string"]`. This expression returns `undefined` because `"any string"` can't be used to index `options` object.

Let's define our function:

```js
export interface IHtmlProperties {
    website?: string
    favIcon?: string;
}


function getHtml(htmlTemplate: string, properties: IHtmlProperties) {
    const options: IHtmlProperties = {
        website: properties.website,
        favIcon: properties.favIcon
    };

    let html = htmlTemplate;

    return (Object.keys(options) as Array<keyof IHtmlProperties>).reduce((acc, key) => {
        const value = options[key];

        return value ? acc.replace('{{' + key + '}}', value) : acc
    }, html);
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wk5p0N)
As you might have noticed, `key` has a correct type. Since expected type of second argument of `replace` is a  `string` we are not allowed to pass `undefined`.

Constant `value` has `string | undefined` type, thats why it is not allowed as an argument. We need to make sure that it is a `string`, this is why I have added ternary operator.

---

Version with `forEach`:

```js
export interface IHtmlProperties {
    website?: string
    favIcon?: string;
}


function getHtml(htmlTemplate: string, properties: IHtmlProperties) {
    const options: IHtmlProperties = {
        website: properties.website,
        favIcon: properties.favIcon
    };

    let html = htmlTemplate;

    (Object.keys(options) as Array<keyof IHtmlProperties>)
        .forEach((key) => {
            const value = options[key];
            if (value) {
                html.replace(`{{${key}}}`, value)
            }
        });

    return html;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! Any reason we can't use the same by typecasting to array of IHTMLProperties keys  with forEach instead of reduce?

Comment: @Ayyappa sure, feel free to use forEach. I made an update. This is the matter of personal preferences